# GitPython repo.git.checkout not checking out branch correctly

Tags: gitpython

I am using following code to checkout or switch the branch within python code,

```py
repo.git.checkout('branch_name')
```

But when the code later executes is still referring to 'master' branch code.

I am using GitPython version 2.1.11.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import git
repo = git.Repo("/home/user/.emacs.d")
```

To checkout a branch:

- to see available branches

```py
>>> repo.heads
[<git.Head "refs/heads/master">, <git.Head "refs/heads/straight">]
```

- you can use the branch name like this:

```py
>>> repo.heads.straight.checkout()
<git.Head "refs/heads/straight">
```

the branch changed to `straight`

If you want to use [git directly](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#using-git-directly)

```py
>>> repo.git.checkout("master")
"Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'."
```

the branch changed to `master`